# c# set condition on contextmenustrip

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, conditional-statements, contextmenustrip

is there anyway to set a condition such as:

when i open a file, it loads some infos on a ListView, the fifth subitem (should be 4 on index count) is loading text, if it is "ETDF", enable an item in the contextmenustrip, if not, disable it, i tried this inside the contextmenustrip but it just gave me an exeption:

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems[4].ToString() != "ETDF")
        {
            editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (listView1.SelectedItems[4].ToString() == "ETDF")
        {
            editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        }
```

am i doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `Enabled` property within the [Opening](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstripdropdown.opening.aspx) event.

```
private void MyContextMenuStrip_Opening(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = (listView1.SelectedItems[4].ToString() == "ETDF");
}
```

Comment: still same exception (ArgumentOutOfRangeException), and i was doing it before.

Comment: Does `listView1.SelectedItems` actually have 5 values in it? `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` seems like your issue is with accessing a non-existent index in `SelectedItems`.

Comment: it depends, what i mean to is the subitem, but i can't access that with my code :/

Comment: What I mean is that the exception seems to be thrown with the line `listView1.SelectedItems[4].ToString()` because you're trying to access the 4th index but there might not be 5 items. In your code, what line actually throws the exception?

Comment: that line, exactly the number 4, it says out of range, just to shorten my question, is there anyway i can access subitems from selected items, the condition is about the subitem[4] of the selected item.

Comment: @Omarrrio I think you want to talk about 4 as the index of a subitem. You may want to try `if(listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1) editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].ToString() == "ETDF");"`

Comment: thanks King, i changed the ToString() to Text as suggested TerryBozzio, and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Did you get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. If so, please check the count.

```
        if (listView1.Items.Count >= 5)
        {
            if (listView1.SelectedItems[4].ToString() != "ETDF")
            {
                editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
            }
            else if (listView1.SelectedItems[4].ToString() == "ETDF")
            {
                editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks, your solution kinda only fixes the exception, but can't really put it as an answer, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (listView1.SelectedItems[4].Text != "ETDF")
        {
            editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = false;
        }
        else if (listView1.SelectedItems[4].Text == "ETDF")
        {
            editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = true;
        }
```

this should solve your problem,error was on calling tostring() when should be text

Comment: it actually helped me find the true answer, thanks, i can't post the answer myself, King found it before, here it is: (king post it so i can mark as answer)
`if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
                editToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text == "ETDF";`